# urldecode in json doesn't work

Tags: php, urldecode

```
require_once('db.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl";

$rs = mysql_query($sql); 

$rows = array();

while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    $rows['Record'][] = $r;
}

print json_encode($rows);

mysql_close($conn);
```

// it works perfect above

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {

    $r = utf8_decode(urldecode($r));

    $rows['Record'][] = $r;
}
```

// it doesn't work above, may be $r is an object
how can I make it works?

Comment: are you try to parse the data from json. what type of answer you want any syntax to show me

Comment: What do you expect from this `$r = utf8_decode(urldecode($r));` to do ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns an array, and you want to pass it to `urldecode`, which waits for a string as a parameter.

To achieve what you want, you should call `urldecode` to all the columns in the returned `$r`.

You can do it like this, for instance:

```
$r = array_map(function($col){
    return utf8_decode(urldecode($col));
}, $r);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: It returns like this 

{"Record":[{"ID":"1","name":"John Smith","email":"johnsmith@gmail.com","tel":"12345678","total":"0","edm":"Y","receipt":"","timestamp":"2016-07-07 12:50:52"},{"ID":"2","name":"Anna Chan ????","email":"annachan@gmail.com","tel":"87654321","total":"200","edm":"N","receipt":"????","timestamp":"2016-07-07 12:52:15"}]} 

???? is chinese characters

if i take away utf8_decode from utf8_decode(urldecode($col));

it returns \u66f4\u65b0\u65e5\u671f 

How can i solve it?